# mysqli_query not working in php despite correctly built query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get what should otherwise be a simple but of php to insert sample data into a table, but something just isn't having any of it.

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams ( 
     token varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
     tname varchar(48) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
     captain varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
     email varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
     phone varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
          PRIMARY KEY (token), 
          UNIQUE KEY name (tname), 
          KEY id (token) 
     )  
     ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");

$tname = "Big Bang";
$cname = "Mike";
$cemail = "test@gmail.com";
$cphone = "123-456-7898";

$teamToken = strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(6, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)));

$query = "INSERT INTO teams (token, tname, captain, email, phone) VALUES ('" . $teamToken . "', '" . $tname . "', '" . $cname . "', '" . $cemail . "', '" . $cphone . "')";

if (mysqli_query($con, $query))
{
    echo "Pass!";
}
else
{
    echo $query;
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

What's odd is the php echos the query, because the mysqli_query result is false, yet the echoed query, when copied and pasted right into phpMyAdmin's terminal, works fine.

I am at my qit's end.

Comment: FYI: I have even tried $query = "INSERT INTO teams (token, tname, captain, email, phone) VALUES ('$teamToken', '$tname', '$cname', '$cemail', '$cphone')";  It produces identical results.

Comment: You should print `mysqli_error($con)` when the query fails so you see the reason for the failure.

Comment: I have tried that, but mysqli_error($con) returns null.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. If a query fails, `mysqli_error` always returns the reason for the failure.

Comment: I have replaced the original if/else block with

mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
echo mysqli_error($con);

Still a blank page. If this helps, the file has 0644 permissions.

EDIT: I greatly appreciate your help, btw :)

Comment: Change it to `die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con))` just so you can see something when it happens.

Comment: I have replaced the if/esle block with:

die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

so I am not even calling the query. The result on the page is "Error:"

Comment: Did you check that `mysqli_connect()` succeeded?

Comment: The connection succeed, but now I modified the first line to be $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password"); mysqli_select_db($con, "mydbname") or die("Could not open the db");
And I am now getting "Could not open the db"

Comment: What does `mysqli_error($con)` say when it can't open the DB?

Comment: It seems I don't have access: Connect Error (1045) Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES) despite the fact that I created the user and the db and granted the user select and insert privileges. I just deleted the user and the database, and recreated everything to no avail.

Comment: No idea, I don't use any shared hosting services. Sounds like something you may need to contact GoDaddy tech support for. But it doesn't sound like a programming issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
```

Edited code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
if(!$con):
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
endif;
```

Its worked fine on my localhost

Comment: Connect Error (1045) Access denied for user 'mytestuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
When I put the password in I get
Connect Error (1045) Access denied for user 'xsoft16dbu'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: you should change root instead of username. Are you running your code on local?

Comment: @MichaelDeLuca You need to add appropriate grants for `mytestuser` to the database.

Comment: I think i should add some background here. This is a Godaddy cPanel shared hosting. I have already went through the wizard to create both the table and the user, and grant the user select and insert access. Beyond that, unless Godaddy's cPanel is pulling me in for a nasty ride, I have no idea why a user I created and granted access still does not have access.

Comment: Ok, now I have simply reset the password to one that is only alphanumeric, and retried: Connect Error (1044) Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' to database 'mydb'

Comment: So in my Godaddy control panel, I have re-added the user to the db, despite it already being listed as having insert and select access to the db. Upon re-adding, my initial code works. I guess we can chalk this one up my misguided assumption of Godaddy's control panel being correct and/or useful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the datatypes of our columns make any problems.

I have once a similar "error" where my token field was to short. phpMyAdmin simply cut the long string to fit (or some thing this) and so it worked inside phpMyAdmin but not with my program.

Please post the CREATE statement of your table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teams` (
  `token` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tname` varchar(48) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `captain` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`token`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`tname`),
  KEY `id` (`token`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: I'm noticing an needed reference to an id key which no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: This will tell him the reason for the error, it won't solve the problem. It should be a comment.

Comment: I replaced the whole if/else block with: mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con)); The result was a blank page

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest go step by step
step 1 : $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
      comment everything other than this statement.
then below write

```
  if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

verify your username password and database name (by default:username=="root" password=="" )

step 2 : add the query statements and print it. also check that all values are within their bounds as specified id DB.

step 3 :if $con and $query are valid then you will get your o/p as you req.

If still you have an error please paste your error statement.

Answer (score 0):

using following to connect:

```
username="root" password=""
```

Your code works fine in my system.

I used `varchar` as datatype. Maybe the length of the `varchar` which you have taken as 12 is less to store the `$teamToken` variable. Try increasing the size.